# Create a partition in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I want to create a partition in Ubuntu with GParted as to install Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu. The problem is that I can't create a partition! I have searched very much (also in here) but although there are countless questions regarding this matter the problem is that they don't work in my case!

Once I open GParted I have the following:

[image]

Once I try to resize the drive it doesn't let me:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible because you have to unmount the partition and, in consequence, you should use a CD or DVD Live of Ubuntu (external Gparted). With the CD Live, you have to reduce the space around half and then copy your partition with Ubuntu in the new free space (to clone). It's recomendable that you install, for precaution, the grub of this cloned partition modifying it for including the first partition and then initialize the system.

Verify that you can boot the two Ubuntu partitions. After that, the first partition is eliminated by using again the CD Live and then install Windows. For dual boot, restore grub from the second partition of Ubuntu and modifying grub inputs for including Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't unmount the partition.
You should boot ubuntu's Live CD and open Gparted from there.
That way the partion won't be mounted and you will be able to resize it.